# jQuery click event fires twice, page has multiple master pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, click, master-pages

I've a page that has a nested Master pages. The control that is firing twice is on the Master Master Page (BasicContentMaster), as well the jquery click event function. How do i prevent firing the click event for the control twice?

The page that inherits two master page (inherits LandingPageMaster first),

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" 
MasterPageFile="~/landingpages/LandingPageMaster.master" CodeBehind="Components.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebsiteProject.Components" %>
```

Then LandingPageMaster inherits BasicContentMaster page

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/BasicContent.Master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="LandingPageMaster.master.vb" Inherits="WebSiteProject.LandingPageMaster" %>
```

Here in BasicContentMaster is where the control that is firing twice when clicked from Component page,

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="BasicContent.master.vb" Inherits="WebSiteProject.BasicContent" %> 

<img id="m-navigation-img" src="/images/nav_menu.png" />
```

jquery click function

```
$('#m-navigation-img').click(function () {
  $('#m-navigation').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: you can use a flag to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#m-navigation-img').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
$('#m-navigation').slideToggle();
});
```